# Windows 7 command line variable equivalent to `$0`

Tags: windows-7, command-line, environment-variables

Is there an environment variable in Windows 7 that is set to the name of the currently running script when I run a script?

I'm looking for the Windows equivalent of the Linux variable `$0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some more info...

%0 is a bit quirky. Depending on how you call the script you will/will not get PATH and extension.

To always get the fully qualified script name this should work   %~f0

To learn about how  %~f0  works ... at a command prompt enter  for /?

FYI... just about every batch language term responds to /?

e.g.

if /?
call /?
del /?
rem /?
cmd /?   (a lot of interesting info for this one)

For a list of batch language terms, at the command prompt enter just    help

Comment: Even better. Thanks so much. I knew about `/?` I just didn't know where to get info about expansion/substitution with that `%~` syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, its  %0

When I tried to post the above short answer I got

Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

```
   * body is too short
```

Now it should be long enough :-)

Answer (score 2):

%0 is what you are looking for.

Comment: I should've guessed! Thanks for the answer. Just what I needed.